# Django reverse_lazy to a URL with a related field id

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have created 2 related models, Applicant and ApplicantStatus. After creating an ApplicantStatus, I would like to reverse_lazy to the applicant detail page based on the applicant status create view entry.

```
class Applicant(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class ApplicantStatus(models.Model):
    applicant = models.ForeignKey(Applicant, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='applicant')
```

Here is the applicant status create view

```
class ApplicantStatusCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    model = ApplicantStatus
    form_class = ApplicantStatusCreateForm
    template_name = 'recruitment/applicant_status_create.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('recruitment:applicant_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

I already know that this will redirect to the non-exisiting page as that applicant doesn't exist yet. This is where I would like to get the id of the applicant from the form and use that in the kwargs, so i will see the applicant detail page with the list of applicant statuses.

Here is the applicant detail view:

```
@login_required()
def applicant_detail_view(request, pk):
    applicant_detail = Applicant.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = ApplicantStatusCreateForm
    applicant_status_detail = ApplicantStatus.objects.filter(applicant__id=applicant_detail.id)

    context = {
        'applicant_detail': applicant_detail,
        'form': form,
        'applicant_status_detail': applicant_status_detail,
    }
    return render(request, 'recruitment/applicant_detail.html', context)
```

The applicant status create form appears in the detail view too as I'm using a modal to display the form in the detail view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer that was waaay simpler than I thought.

In the applicant status create view, I just replaced:

```
def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('recruitment:applicant_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

With this:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('recruitment:applicant_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.applicant.id})
```

I hope this helps you too.